# Explain me "document.getElementById("div_name").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;"

Tags: javascript

I would really appreciate If anyone can explain methe following:

```
document.getElementById("txtHint2").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
```

I understand that result (right side after equal sign) will be written within div tag in this case...But what is this RESPONSETEXT actually?

I have html calling some *.js. In this I have url to php. In php is command connect to database and give results after my query.

So result of this query sholud be related to =responseText ...

I am confused and not so familiar about this ...Please help me!!!

Comment: *(reference)* http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-responsetext-attribute

Answer (score 1):

you may read;

> [Using jQuery and JSON with AJAX responseText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/984329/using-jquery-and-json-with-ajax-responsetext)

Answer (score 0):

It contains the content from the URL you requested using the XMLHttpRequest object.

Answer (score 0):

The object `xmlHttp` has the property `responseText` that is the response of your XML HTTP Request ("ajax" return). It's like when you load a page in a browser and you get your page.

---

This object has many properties, like:

> **responseText**: Returns the response data as a string
>
> **responseXML**: Returns the response data as XML data

Referece: http://www.w3schools.com/dom/default.asp.

Answer (score 0):

`xmlHttp.responseText` is the body of the response from the server. It is whatever was sent back from the server based on the request (specified in the `xmlHttp` object). It could be a simple string of text, or a snippet of HTML, or JSON to be parsed and used by your code.

Answer (score 0):

the requested url will generate an output(text/html). This output is sent to the client(requested page) through xmlHttp.responseText;

You may also get xml as an output, then you need to use xmlHttp.responseXML; you need to parse this and use it in your application..